# Alternative idioms to "to put the whole matter into a nutshell"?

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

I need some alternatives to introduce summarization on the final paragraph of non-technical chapters or longer blog articles. Known terms like *summary* often sound a bit technical to me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few more examples, some of which are *highly* informal:

- The short version is ...
- Essentially, ...
- In essence, ...
- To make a long story short, ...
- The point [to take away from this] is ...
- In review: ... *(esp. before organized text, like a bulleted list)*
- So, what do we know? ... *(good for writing that is **educational** or **technical**, but also **informal**)*

**Edit:**

- To recap, ...
- To rehash: ...
- To wrap things up, ...
- So, going back over [the main points] ...
- Looking at what we've covered [so far] ...
- [At this point,] we have established that ...

The wordier ones can obviously be varied: "Going back over ..." could just as easily be "Let's go back over ..." or "Now, to go back over ..." and so on. It all depends on how formal, personal, and serious you want to be.

Comment: @ROFL dont worry according to my last question latin anyway is a foreign language here http://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/3439/is-it-good-style-to-use-latin-phrases-in-english-scientific-literature  your examples look like from a list, want to share? ;)

Comment: I would if I had one. I just came up with these myself. Although I suppose the entire point of Stack Exchange is *creating* such lists, really. =)

Comment: checkmate! ding ding ding...

Comment: @Hauser: Your other question was migrated because it was about writing style. Also, Latin *is* a foreign language.

Comment: @simchona no critics, just irony, i got better answers there than probably here. Still i think it belong to here as the question was, can i write latin phrases and do native english speaker have a rudimentary latin vocabulary (e.g. you have stronger latin roots then germany) and do they understand but writers.SE is about how you formulate something indpendent of the language. Maybe thats a misview, i didnt know this site...the german language site accepted same question and voted up...

Comment: @Hauser: You asked whether it was "good style" to include English. This doesn't ask whether or not English speakers know Latin; it asks whether you can throw it in there and have good writing style. You asked "what do you do", which isn't really in the scope of EL&U. We can't write your paper for you.

Comment: @simchona you should simply make a link in the sidebar to writers.se as 99% will come to this site and ask similar questions out of alternatives. IMHO its natural someone ask about writing style on a language site. If the majority does use latin phrases, than its ok. A diff. voting of an answer - yes its ok - no its not would have cleared this up as it it on german.SE. Its a matter of convention of majority as it is in German, i wasnt expecting an exact answer. Can you make a poll here?!?

Comment: @Hauser: Writing style is not covered in the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq) for this site. Questions about specific English word choice? Yes. Questions about how to write a document? NO. That is left to [Writers.SE].

Answer (score 3):

- In sum
- In a word
- To sum up
- In short
- Briefly

You can encapsulate the body of the work in a brief summation.

Comment: +1 but imho some of your examples also make the reader to suppose the following summarization will be short ;) Thats what i like about the nutshell example. You can write a full A4 paragraph after it (briefly, in a word, in short dont work here imho so well) Sry but this just came into my mind after reading your answer, should i edit my question concerning this? thx

Comment: Not all of these would work for all cases, no. Depends on your text and your format. Just some more arrows for your quiver.

Comment: @Hauser, I don't understand how "in a nutshell" would not make the reader suppose that the summarization would be short.  Summarizations are *supposed* to be short (relative to the source material) regardless of how you introduce them.

Comment: @Hellion briefly means short itself, same as *in A WORD*, nutshell is a object. I know it is very subtly and subjective nuances, but for non-technical summarizations and esp. introduction/transition argumentum examples sound more aesthetical TO ME. Probably a matter of taste

Comment: @Hauser - In short is relative.  If you are summarizing a 300 page book in 2 pages that the expectation of in short.  In a word is much diffrent.  That is relating a concept to a single entity.  In a word, War and Peace is LONG.  A summary is a standard writing technique.  I think you are looking for something more specific but have asked a the question in a way that is as likely to find a good answer for you as a random selection from a thesaurus.

Comment: @Chad to put the whole matter into a nutshell is a metaphor, the raven examples are not, argumentums look much more analog despite they are no metaphors but IMHO better for prose text. This is a language site, there will never be a absolutely exact question an answer, i see your points, but its not worth the time to discuss it further. I asked for alternatives to this metaphor/common idiom. Im no native, so i cant give a uberexakt question and definition, but the question was imho obvious and Raven answer not worthless, i will use this too.

Comment: @Hauser OK you want a metaphor... That is different than just a word or phrase that you originally asked for.

Comment: @Chad i asked and tagged for idioms...idiom is not really different to metaphor if you hover over it. My question was edited...Nobody is perfect! Idiom or Metaphor? ;)