# To make a long story short, formal or informal

Tags: formality

I know from [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35706/alternative-idioms-to-to-put-the-whole-matter-into-a-nutshell) a couple of good alternatives for "to cut/make the long story short", I'm just curious if it is formal to use it or not.

Comment: This expression can be used in both formal AND informal forms of speech.

Comment: Neither.  It's just like "to be in a hurry" or "to get rid of something".   Formal/Informal  doesn't apply here, which means they can be used in any situation.

Comment: The indefinite article is important to the idiom. The idiom is "to make a long story short," not "to make the long story short."

Comment: I would only use it in informal conversation, or certain types of writing, such as a chatty magazine article.

Answer (score 1):

It is an idiomatic expression (**cliche** - thanks @Accumulation) and, though it is polite, it is not *formal* in the sense that it would be out of place in, for example, a business proposal.

But that is contextual, since it would be acceptable to use the expression in diplomatic speeches.

It is somewhat casual and somewhat familiar. It might be in place in a testimony, but it would not be appropriate in a legal document.

All about context.

"To cut a long story short" would be even more casual.

Comment: It's not really idiomatic. Its meaning is transparent from the constituent words. So more of a cliche than an idiom.

Comment: good one. updatged

Answer (score 0):

[long story short](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/long-story-short) is in the *Cambridge Advanced Learner's Dictionary & Thesaurus*.  Legal documents are full of their own [idioms](http://www.idiomconnection.com/legal.html) so I wouldn't bar it based on that.  Remember that idioms often don't translate well (into other languages) and are often opaque to non-native speakers so know your audience.

Comment: Just to clarify, I view "long story short, ..." as reasonably formal.